# While adding an effect to viewbox the object is grayed out

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have added an effect to Viewbox as below:

```
<Viewbox Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,12.5,65,0" >
    <Viewbox.Effect>
        <effects:RippleEffect Magnitude="0" Frequency="0" />
    </Viewbox.Effect>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="MinimizeRect" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="White" Fill="Transparent"/>
        <Image Source="Images/Minimize.png" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
    <Viewbox.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" >
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Magnitude" To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0.3" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Frequency" To="40" Duration="0:0:0.3" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="DodgerBlue" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="MinimizeRect"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" >
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Magnitude" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Frequency" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="MinimizeRect"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Viewbox.Triggers>
</Viewbox>
```

But my image and Stroke of rectangle does not remain white. They are grayed. What might be the problem here?

Here is the image.

[image]

In the above image Ripple effect is added to Minimize button. Any effect is not added to close button.

Comment: These are always hard to manage by simple event triggers.  For example, it might work perfectly if you 1) hover over the button 2) wait for the animation to complete 3) move the mouse out from over the button.  For something like this, I'd definitely recommend you use [visual states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx), which work all the time without much fuss.

Comment: Just a bit of guessing. You use the ViewBox to scale the content. That works but you should know more or less the ViewBox takes a "screenshot" and scales that. And downscalling an image might result in strange results. Especially blured borders that turn from white to gray.

Comment: Does the effect have to be applied to the ViewBox? Judging by the graphics it might make more sense to make them into Geometry Path data instead so they're actually vector xaml images and wont care how they're manipulated but stay the same resolution instead of using raster images.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode to HighQuality like so:

```
<Image Source="Images/Minimize.png" Margin="5"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
```